# Good NAS for backup

Tags: backup, nas, sftp

I have a server (multiple planned) which I would need to back up on a regular basis. The server is running Debian Squeeze.

What kind of NAS hardware would you suggest that would be able to do the following:

- Be capable of being accessed through a secure ftp connection through the internet (NON-LAN)
- Be capable of RAID 1
  I have planned 2 WD Caviar Black 2TB as the disc media.

What NAS would be optimal for my purporses? Any specific brand that is favorable?

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Axel. As you can read in our [FAQ], we do not allow questions asking for shopping recommendation. I'm fairly certain almost any NAS these days allows you to set up RAID 1 and an SFTP server. You'll just have to look into the feature lists of various vendors. There are plenty of websites that also do reviews for certain products, and most vendors also have forums set up for their customers to discuss issues et cetera.

Comment: Oh okay. Guess I'll have to take the hard way and check up stuff for myself. Was hoping for someone with a little bit more experience to point me in some kind of direction. Glad we got this sorted out!

Comment: As I said, you'll find plenty of reviews online. I'm sorry that this is not the right place. To add my 2 cents though and get you started: I personally *love* QNAP devices and have never had a problem with these. Even their cheap products are massive in terms of features. ReadyNAS are okay too. Buffalo, not so much. Just my personal opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Readynas hardware... Even after Netgear bought them out.